# Confusion about where should put the [unowned self]

Tags: swift, strong-references, unowned-references

I have a retained cycle so my viewcontroller's deinit won't be called, and I'm trying to resolve this my adding [unowned self], but I'm not too sure where to put the unowned in my cases:

## Case 1

```
class YADetailiViewController: UIViewController {
 var subscription: Subscription<YAEvent>?

 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    if let query = self.event.subscribeQuery() {
        self.subscription = Client.shared.subscribe(query)
        self.subscription?.handle(Event.updated) {
            query, object in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                [unowned self] in// Put unowned here won't break the cycle, but it does compile and run 
                self.pageViewLabel.text = String(object.pageViews) + " VIEW" + ((object.pageViews > 1) ? "S" : "")
            }
        }
    }
 }
}
```

## Case 2

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    if let query = self.event.subscribeQuery() {
        self.subscription = Client.shared.subscribe(query)
        self.subscription?.handle(Event.updated) {
            [unowned self] query, object in // Put unowned breaks the cycle, and deinit is called
                DispatchQueue.main.async { 
                    self.pageViewLabel.text = String(object.pageViews) + " VIEW" + ((object.pageViews > 1) ? "S" : "")
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I'm curious what's the differences between these two scenarios and why one works but not the other

Comment: In the first one, you have omitted `in` after `[unowned self]`. Is that deliberate?

Comment: I think the difference has to do with when `self` is captured. In the first one, `self` has already been captured in the outer closure by the time you declare `self` to be `unowned` in the inner closure. In the second one, you prevent that by declaring `self` to be `unowned` in the outer closure. See http://www.swiftarchive.org/Nested-functions-and-reference-capturing-td667.html which may be relevant here (though I could be wrong)

Comment: @matt, good catch, just added the `in`

Comment: Apart from the issue consider that the `async` closure of GCD does not cause a retain cycle so adding `[unowned self]` there is meaningless anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, as correctly mentioned by @matt the problem is related to the time when `self` is captured. In fact int this code `self` is captured twice:

- When the outer closure is passed to the `handle` method
- When the inner closure is passed to the `async` method (during the `handle` closure execution)

The outer closure needs `self` to pass it to the inner closure, otherwise the inner closure won't be able to capture it.

The nature or retain cycle is the following: `self`(YADetailiViewController) -> `subscription` -> closure (`handle` parameter) -> `self`. To break this cycle it's enough to not retain `self` in that (outer) closure. That's why the second code sample works.

The second capture of `self` (in the inner closure) happens only when the outer closure is executed and lasts until that `async` block is executed - usually it's quite a short time.

In the first code sample you're not breaking the cycle. The second capture of `self` doesn't happen but the first one (causing thy cycle) is still present.

And if your `handle` closure can still be called when the view controller is already deinited/released then as suggested by @AdrianBobrowski you should use `weak` instead of `unowned` to prevent possible crash.